# How do you change xibs to change on-screen items?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

How would I do this? ***[EDIT] I have 2 `.xibs` and 2 `ViewControllers`. Is there a way to "switch `.xibs`?**
<sup>(I'm a novice)</sup>

If I had an `Options` button and I wanted it to change what's onscreen, how would I do this when it is tapped?
Would I need a new `.xib` or `ViewController` file?

[image]
[image]
[image]
Image 1: Modified Auto-Genned `.xib`
Image 2: Files
Image 3: Second `.xib` (with UIViewController.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea, in my opinion, would be to create a new view controller and accompanying xib file (check the "With XIB for user interface" box when creating it). You can then present this controller using the `presentViewController:animated:completion` method of the parent view controller, which is the one you have the screenshot of.

Alternately, you could create a UINavigationController as the root controller of your application. Then you could push the settings view controller into the navigation controller and get the slide transition effect that is used in most table-based applications.

There are other ways to do this, such as using storyboards as yliu1021 mentioned. That would work for something like a settings screen, but I find it harder to use with more dynamic interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options. The first is to create an UIView and present that on top of that view and another would be to create a new ViewController file along with a .xib file. You should look into using storyboards however because it'll make all of this very simple and easy.